# uniform convergence on compact sets in a compactly generated Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a  Hausdorff space that is determined by an upward filtered family $\mathcal{K}=\{K_{\alpha} : \alpha \in I \}$ of compact subsets of $X$, i. e., $X=\cup_{\alpha \in I} K_{\alpha}$ and also :

A subset $F$ is open in $X$ if
and only if $F\cap K_{\alpha}$ is open in $K_{\alpha}$ for all
$\alpha \in I$. (Equivalently,  a subset $F$ is closed in $X$ if
and only if $F\cap K_{\alpha}$ is closed in $K_{\alpha}$ for all
$\alpha \in I$.)

Is the
topology (on $C(X)$) of uniform convergence on compact sets $\{K_{\alpha} :
\alpha \in I \}$  equal to the topology of uniform
convergence on all compact subsets in $X$?

Note that: $C(X)$ is the space of all continuous complex functions on $X$. And also, the
topology (on $C(X)$) of uniform convergence on compact sets $\{K_{\alpha} :
\alpha \in I \}$  equal to the topology induced by the family of seminorms $\{||\cdot||_{ \alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$, where $||f||_{
\alpha}:= \sup \{|f(x)| : x \in K_{\alpha} \}$.

Comment: I think you might want to assume that $\mathcal{K}$ is "cofinal" in the compact sets: for all compact $K \subseteq X$, $K \subseteq K_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in I$, to connect the two topologies, as it were. Or does that follow already from the assumptions ?

Comment: Dear Henno, your idea is interesting. If we can prove that for
every compact $K\subseteq X$, $K\subseteq K_{\alpha}$ for some
$\alpha \in I$, then the problem is easily solved.

Comment: It need not hold, see @EricWofsey's example. But you could assume it holds, or show it does in some concrete case.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, let $X=[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal{K}$ be the set of countable closed subsets of $X$ (these determine the topology since a subset of $X$ is closed iff it is sequentially closed).  For each $K\in\mathcal{K}$, choose a function $f_K\in C(X)$ which is $1$ on $K$ but $0$ at some point of $X\setminus K$.  These functions then form a net $(f_K)$ in $C(X)$ which converges uniformly to $1$ on each $K\in\mathcal{K}$ but does not converge to $1$ uniformly on $X$.

More generally, the same construction would work for any compact Hausdorff space $X$ with such a family $\mathcal{K}$ which does not include $X$ itself.

Comment: Dear Eric,Your answer is absolutely creative. Thanks